# Add file into a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have an online user admission portal, in which I have 4 resume columns - for father, mother, guardian and applicant. User uploads these resumes when he applies for a particular course. Which method should I use to store these uploaded resumes (files in `.docx` format) to my database?

1. I have an uploader and I create a folder then save `.docx` file into this folder and store the file path in a `filepath` table column;

   or
2. I have a column of type `varbinary(MAX)` and store `.docx` file itself in this column.

Which method is more secure and has better performance?

Comment: On my opinion, better is to save in file system and path on tables. In order to otpimize database volume with what ever that it means. I am totaly against saving byte[] in database.

Comment: But that my personal opinion though what i have seen.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of storing the files in a column in the database, I would have a look at using [FILESTREAM (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx)

> FILESTREAM enables SQL Server-based applications to store unstructured
>   data, such as documents and images, on the file system. Applications
>   can leverage the rich streaming APIs and performance of the file
>   system and at the same time maintain transactional consistency between
>   the unstructured data and corresponding structured data.

Comment: Sir it means i have saved docx file itself in table column and read it from my front end(c#)

Comment: It would also depend on files size and usage pattern. `FILESTREAM` is designed for large files (>1MB on average)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer option #2, because then your resumes are contained within the database and you don't have to worry about backing up external files outside the database. I think this option is also more secure, because you don't have to worry about NTFS permissions either. Many times SQL Server is placed behind a firewall that's between app/web and sql server. In that sense, your data is more secure. It depends on the architecture of your infrastructure.

Remember that databases can grow very large and you will have to pay attention to your query performance. When done right, no problems at all.